# share a link by whatsapp that opens a specific application instead of browser

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview

I have an app programmed in java for android with a range of devices from sdk 23 to 33.

This app only incorporates a webview where I load my web page/app https://tcg-wallet.ga

a brief explanation of what the site does: it does web scraping to obtain TCG card price data and everything is referenced to a search url volatile.

Inside the website I have added an html button with the intention of opening the share dialog using javascript:

```
const shareData = {
    title: 'Search Price',
    text: 'Search Card by: "' + document.getElementById('search').value + '"',
    url: document.URL
}

const btn = document.getElementById('share-url');

if (typeof btn !== 'undefined') {
    btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            console.log(window.AndroidShareHandler);
            if (typeof (window.AndroidShareHandler) != 'undefined') {
                window.AndroidShareHandler.shareSearch(JSON.stringify(shareData));
            } else {
                alert('shared Working');
                await navigator.share(shareData);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('[Error]: Error on share link!');
        }
    });
}
```

and i received it on the app on android via:

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptShareInterface(context),"AndroidShareHandler");
```

I successfully tried to share this data like this to other apps:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void shareSearch(String javascript_data) {
    try {

        JSONObject search = new JSONObject(javascript_data);
        String title = search.getString("title");
        String text = search.getString("text");
        String url = search.getString("url");
        String content = title+"\n"+text+"\n\n"+url;

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
        app_context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, content));

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

but the result is not as desired (the problem)

When I share the information, for example through WhatsApp, the message must be sent as plain text and by including a url like this (https://tcg-wallet.ga/home?search=MP21-EN056&event=search) if they click on it link, it opens automatically in the android web browser and not in my application.

Question: How can I register in the android operating system or configuration that when trying to open the url my application opens and that I pass the url arguments to it.

update it is my `intent-filter`:

```xml
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare an intent-filter on your AndroidManifest.xml, something like that:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="tcg-wallet.ga"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Inside the Activity you want to manage the url

Comment: ok, but the user who receives the shared link is receiving the url through a whatsapp message... let me check if it happens... that if this user clicks on the url, if he opens the application... XD

Comment: ok, i find my intent- filter ... i must override or add your setting ???

Comment: Your app only have one activity? add the content of my intent-filter to yours, then on your Activity inside onCreate method read the url from intent.data

Comment: yes, everything happens in my main activity, what is not clear to me is that I already have two similar lines, in the filter one says MAIN and you suggest VIEW; I have another one that indicates LAUNCHER and you suggest the same one but that indicates: DEFAULT and other BROWSABLE ...  I am left wondering if I should overwrite my filter or add the content of yours to the end of the filter...

Comment: My other question is about: "read the url from intent.data" I honestly don't know how to do this XD

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking . "Include the BROWSABLE category. It is required in order for the intent filter to be accessible from a web browser. Without it, clicking a link in a browser cannot resolve to your app." In the same link you can find how to read the url: "Read data from incoming intents"

Comment: the truth is that I don't understand what I'm doing wrong; I have already read the documentation, I even included the code that you have indicated ... but when trying the app:

Comment: 1) the icon of the installed app is not visible (not resolved).
2) I received a nullPoint error because the intent was empty (null), add controls to avoid this and that the app opens without receiving an intent (resolved).
3) when trying to open a url that was sent in whatsapp, the google browser opens directly ... it does nothing as expected. It is supposed to open the app... at least to evaluate that I am receiving the intent and the new url.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of research I have found what I needed to implement certainly:

1. Edit **AndroidManifest.xml:**
   you must include new `intent-filters`, place them after the filter that brings the application by default, like this:

```xml
             <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="tcg-wallet.ga" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="app"
                    android:host="com.icarosnet.tcgwallet" />
            </intent-filter>
```

2. then you must make sure in your `MainActivity.java` to evaluate if you are receiving the intent:

```java
        Uri url_shared = getIntent().getData();

        if(url_shared != null){
            Url = url_shared.toString();
        }
```

once the url variable has been processed it will contain the full web address.

3. At this point we have already done the main part of the development or integration of the intent reading, but even so the application will not open automatically: for this we will need to enable the validation of the intent host:
4. our intent-filter must contain the self-verification instruction  `android:autoVerify="true"` and on our website we must have a digital signature resource json file that links to the application:

`https://your-host-domain/.well-know/assetlinks.json` 
or 
`http://your-host-domain/.well-know/assetlinks.json`

with json content like:

```json
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "package_namespace",
      "package_name": "com.package_name.myapp",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
       "14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Relationed documentation:
[Link-1](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks) and [Link-2](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started?utm_source=developer.android.com&utm_medium=referral)